# Microsoft Graph API Managed Identity

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to gain access for Graph API for a Function App managed identity. This must be done through a Azure DevOps YAML pipeline. I have this example script from MS how to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell

```
# Install the module.
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser

# The tenant ID
$TenantId = "856ea157-bf1d-43df-af37-bbfbc0072578"

# The name of your web app, which has a managed identity.
$webAppName = "func..." 
$resourceGroupName = "rg..."

# The name of the app role that the managed identity should be assigned to.
$appRoleName = "User.Read.All"

# Get the web app's managed identity's object ID.
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $TenantId
$managedIdentityObjectId = (Get-AzFunctionApp -Name $webAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).identity.principalid

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'Application.Read.All','AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All'

# Get Microsoft Graph app's service principal and app role.
$serverApplicationName = "Microsoft Graph"
$serverServicePrincipal = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$serverApplicationName'")
$serverServicePrincipalObjectId = $serverServicePrincipal.Id

$appRoleId = ($serverServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $appRoleName }).Id

# Assign the managed identity access to the app role.
New-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment `
    -ServicePrincipalId $managedIdentityObjectId `
    -PrincipalId $managedIdentityObjectId `
    -ResourceId $serverServicePrincipalObjectId `
    -AppRoleId $appRoleId
```

I have a Azure Resource Manager Service connection in DevOps. I'll like to auth with this Service Principal when executing the above script.
In my YAML pipeline I have tried with this task, but it keep waiting for logon like when I execute it locally.

```
  - job: DeployScript
    displayName: DeployScript

    steps:
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'Sub:DEV/TST - Isolated - Dyn365.RG:d365intplat-tst'
        ScriptType: 'FilePath'
        ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Azure/Policies/GraphApiManagedIdentityRoleAssignment.ps1'
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Comment: Providing a Tenant parameter to Connect-AzAccount inits an interactive login. Try - Identity as parameter. I guess the azureSubscription value in pipeline is your service connection.